# Single partition mounted to multiple directories with different files

Tags: debian, docker, mount, systemd

I have a systemd mount for a single partition which results in three different directories being mounted.

The file /etc/systemd/system/var-lib-docker.mount

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount LSSD Volume at boot

[Mount]
What=UUID="8f9f5f23-6cf3-448a-85d1-74524dffe48a"
Where=/var/lib/docker
Type=ext4
Options=rw,relatime,data=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which results in:

```
$ grep sda /proc/mounts

/dev/sda1 /var/lib/docker ext4 rw,relatime,nodelalloc,data=journal 0 0
/dev/sda1 /var/lib/docker/plugins ext4 rw,relatime,nodelalloc,data=journal 0 0
/dev/sda1 /var/lib/docker/aufs ext4 rw,relatime,nodelalloc,data=journal 0 0
```

I expect all the directories mounted to the same partition to contain the same set of files. How are these three different directories all pointing to the same partition and still containing different sets of files?

```
$ ls  /var/lib/docker/plugins/
storage  tmp

$ ls  /var/lib/docker/aufs/
diff  layers  mnt

$ ls  /var/lib/docker/
aufs  builder  containerd  containers  image  lost+found  network  overlay2  plugins  runtimes  swarm  tmp  trust  volumes
```

This is running on Debian Stretch on a C2L instance on Scaleway.

```
Linux jenkins 4.10.8-docker-1 #1 SMP Tue Apr 4 16:18:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.0 (stretch)
Release:    9.0
Codename:   stretch
```

Comment: That's interesting. It might have something to do with Scaleway's slightly odd SAN, but then again it might be Debian.

Comment: It seems your systemd implementation of mount is doing bind mounting for all directories under `/dev/sda1` partition. This is possibly a bug related to Debian or Systemd. Does the same happen when you use a different operating system like CentOS or Ubuntu on Scaleway?

Comment: I have abandoned Scaleway as a production environment and moved to a FaaS offering